# Response.Redirect problam

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a basic project with a menu bar that the server executes on each page. I want to prevent the access to the pages for unregistered users, so I added this code

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("HomePageWebSite.aspx");
```

When I load the HomePage by its self it works normaly, but when I use this code, the browser says that it can't find this page(unable to access this page). I checked the url of the homepage and it's the same one that the server can't access to.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are your other pages in a sub directory?  Is so use `Response.Redirect("~/HomePageWebSite.aspx");`

Answer (score 6):

If your home page is in the root change the code as below:

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("/HomePageWebSite.aspx");
```

The "/" in the beginning will always lookup from the root directory. If you do not give the "/" it will always lookup in the current directory which will results in problems if you have nested directories.

Comment: Did you give the absolute path of HomePageWebSite.aspx?

Comment: What do you mean by absulute path?